# How to get started with angular2 in nw.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, nw.js

How can I get a working 'hello world' for angular 2 under nw.js?

I successfully got a working angular 2 app using this guide:

https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html

and a working nw.js app using this one:

https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-your-first-nw-js-desktop-application-in-less-than-5-minutes

Combining the two I get this:

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.0",
    "systemjs": "0.19.6",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.0",
    "zone.js": "0.5.10"
  },
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": ""
}
```

`index.html`:

```
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>

    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <script src="env/lib/node_modules/angular2-quickstart/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="env/lib/node_modules/angular2-quickstart/node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.umd.js"></script>
    <script src="env/lib/node_modules/angular2-quickstart/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-all.umd.js"></script>

    <!-- 2. Load our 'modules' -->
    <script src='app/app.component.js'></script>
    <script src='app/boot.js'></script>

  </head>

  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>

</html>
```

`app/boot.js`:

```
(function(app) {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    ng.platform.browser.bootstrap(app.AppComponent);
  });
})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

`app/app.component.js`:

```
(function(app) {
  app.AppComponent =
    ng.core.Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>'
    })
    .Class({
      constructor: function() {}
    });
})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

To install node and dependencies I ran (I ended up with node 5.4.1; nodeenv is https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nodeenv/0.13.6):

```
nodeenv --prebuilt env
source env/bin/activate
npm install -g nw
npm install -g
```

Then to run the app under `nw`:

```
nw .
```

If I replace the index.html with a simple plain HTML 'hello world', I see that display in nw fine.  However, with the angular 2 index.html, I see the "Loading..." message from my app in the browser, and this on the terminal from which I launched nw:

```
[22627:0117/010210:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(170)] Running without the SUID sandbox! See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment for more information on developing with the sandbox on.
ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
[22627:0117/010210:ERROR:nw_shell.cc(336)] TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at Object.apply (file:///home/me/dev/angular2-quickstart/env/lib/node_modules/angular2-quickstart/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:941:35)
    at Object.apply (file:///home/me/dev/angular2-quickstart/env/lib/node_modules/angular2-quickstart/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:835:22)
    at Object.apply (file:///home/me/dev/angular2-quickstart/env/lib/node_modules/angular2-quickstart/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:301:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (file:///home/me/dev/angular2-quickstart/env/lib/node_modules/angular2-quickstart/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:38:14)
    at Object.1.../core (file:///home/me/dev/angular2-quickstart/env/lib/node_modules/angular2-quickstart/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:40:4)
    at s (file:///home/me/dev/angular2-quickstart/env/lib/node_modules/angular2-quickstart/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:19:254)
    at e (file:///home/me/dev/angular2-quickstart/env/lib/node_modules/angular2-quickstart/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:19:425)
    at file:///home/me/dev/angular2-quickstart/env/lib/node_modules/angular2-quickstart/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:19:443
[22627:0117/010210:INFO:CONSOLE(941)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined", source: file:///home/me/dev/angular2-quickstart/env/lib/node_modules/angular2-quickstart/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js (941)
[22627:0117/010211:ERROR:nw_shell.cc(336)] reflect-metadata shim is required when using class decorators
[22627:0117/010211:INFO:CONSOLE(2398)] "Uncaught reflect-metadata shim is required when using class decorators", source: file:///home/me/dev/angular2-quickstart/env/lib/node_modules/angular2-quickstart/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-all.umd.js (2398)
[22627:0117/010211:ERROR:nw_shell.cc(336)] ReferenceError: ng is not defined
    at window.app.window.app (file:///home/me/dev/angular2-quickstart/app/app.component.js:3:5)
    at file:///home/me/dev/angular2-quickstart/app/app.component.js:10:3
[22627:0117/010211:INFO:CONSOLE(3)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: ng is not defined", source: file:///home/me/dev/angular2-quickstart/app/app.component.js (3)
[22627:0117/010211:ERROR:nw_shell.cc(336)] ReferenceError: ng is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (file:///home/me/dev/angular2-quickstart/app/boot.js:3:5)
[22627:0117/010211:INFO:CONSOLE(3)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: ng is not defined", source: file:///home/me/dev/angular2-quickstart/app/boot.js (3)
[22656:0117/010213:WARNING:channel.cc(553)] Failed to send message to remove remote endpoint (local ID 2147483649, remote ID 3)
[22656:0100/000000:WARNING:channel.cc(553)] Failed to send message to remove remote endpoint (local ID 1, remote ID 1)
```

I'm on Linux.

Comment: Is angular loaded when you look at the net tab in the developer console?

Comment: @LarryLane how would I know?  Type ng at the console?  I get an Uncaught ReferenceError: ng is not defined

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your angular JavaScript file is not being loaded. That is why ng is undefined I believe.

To enable the toolbar for development purposes place the following property setting in your package.json file.

```
 "toolbar": true,
```

Take a look at the following screenshot so you can begin troubleshooting.

[image]

After you click on the network tab hit F5 to refresh the page so that you can see which files have and have not loaded.

Comment: Though I don't see any network traffic logged there re angular JS files, I don't think it's possible that that's because they are not being loaded.  That's because on the console, it prints the lines of certain angular JS files at which it hit a problem (see my original question).  How can it hit a problem at a specific line of a file it did not load?  The same is true of the two .js files in my project.

Comment: What do you mean you don't see any network traffic logged? You should see your javascript files loaded under the network tab.

Comment: I mean that I don't see any files loaded under the network tab.

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to tell you to hit f5 after you click on the network tab. Then you will see which files have and have not been loaded.

Comment: Oh, right, thanks.  I see all the following loaded: index.html, angular2-polyfills.js, Rx.umd.js, angular2-all.umd.js, app.component.js, and boot.js

Comment: I don't know what the correct order is :-(  They are loaded in the order I listed them in my comment above, though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100873/discussion-between-larry-lane-and-croad-langshan).