# Javascript - Angular 2 and nw.js WebSocket context

Tags: javascript, websocket, angular, nw.js

I'm having what I think might be the exact same problem as this question: [How to get started with angular2 in nw.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34833992/how-to-get-started-with-angular2-in-nw-js/34855997#34855997)

I posted some additional details there to try and help figure out what's going on, but everything I contributed was deleted and I was told to ask a new question.

---

I followed the Angular 2 'quickstart' javascript tutorial found on the angular website.

Then I tried running my app with nw.js, and it fails to load. I am running on Windows 10, and I used the same angular2 app, with a slightly different package.json:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run lite",
    "lite": "lite-server"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.0",
    "systemjs": "0.19.6",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.0",
    "zone.js": "0.5.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "lite-server": "^1.3.1"
  },
  "window": {
    "title": "TEST",
    "frame": true,
    "toolbar": true,
    "width": 1200,
    "height": 675,
    "icon": "icon.png"
  }
}
```

My app does load correctly when I run it from the command line with

```
npm start
```

But when I run my app with

```
nw .
```

I get this error in my console: https://i.stack.imgur.com/scEPa.png

And here's the line in code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaL2n.png

EDIT: The below section is probably not relevant, as it's referencing the Node context of nwjs, not the window context.

<strike>Also, I just found this link with the following information: Some other browser features (such as Worker and WebSocket interfaces) are also unavailable in the Node's context. github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Differences-of-JavaScript-contexts ... anyone know what this means or if it's impacting angular2-polyfills.js compatibility with nw.js?</strike>

Comment: image hyperlinks are missed

Comment: Stack overflow wouldn't let me add the image links at first but I have edited them back in, thanks